# How Do I Only Show items that have <2 on the graph?

Tags: google-sheets

I need to make a bar graph in google sheets to show how many complaints each dealer received, however I don't want the graph to show the dealers with only >2 complaints. How can I make the graph only show dealers that have had more than 2 complaints?

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with realistic-looking data.

Comment: Hi, welcome to WebApps. The title of your question, and the question are inconsistent. Title="show only <2 on graph"; question= "show only dealers with more than 2".

Answer (score 1):

Use `filter()` or `query()` to create a copy of your data table that only includes rows where the number of complaints is greater than or equal to two. Then create a chart using the result table.

Comment: For example, if "Dealer name" is in Column A, and "Number of complaints" is in Column B, then a filter might look like this: `=filter(A1:B10,B1:B10>2)` and the equivalent query might like this: `=query(A1:B10,"select A, B where B>2",1)`